# Rename a tag after its creation

Tags: support, feature-request

I recently posted a question and created the [xhrget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xhrget) tag when posting it, but then I recognized that it would be better if I named it [dojo.xhrget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dojo.xhrget) so it would be more significant, but I just realized that I can't rename it and I can just Edit its excerpt or its description.

So I created the new [dojo.xhrget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dojo.xhrget) tag, and there was two tags referring to the same thing, but in the end only one of them got approved.

So the question is how can we rename a tag after its creation ? 
Is it even possible ?

Comment: Tags that are not used get automatically culled by the system. So you can create a new tag and just don't use the old one.